# Adding an AlertDialog - Undefined constructor

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

For 10 hours I've being trying to add an alertdialog to my app but not sucessfull, I think that's gonna be a stupid question but I'm realy new on this, tried to research in many links like those [AlertDialog - Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029156/alertdialog-not-working) ; [SDK Android AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html), but even that I still have problems.

Actually, I got every time basicly the same problem:

Here the code I copied from the link to help me:

```
public void dbFail(){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Reset...");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure?");
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              // here you can add functions
           }
        });
        alertDialog.show(); 
    }
```

and Here the problem:

The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(ConnectDB¹) is undefined.

¹- It's the name of my context

So, what do I realy need to do? I didnt see anyone talking about implement this constructor...Do I need to implement a method inside the AlertDialog.Builder calling, describing what is he supposed to do?

---

Comment: I think this is enough - `new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context needs to be an Activity.

Judging by your error `The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(ConnectDB) is undefined.`, I'm guessing that you are trying to show this AlertDialog in a database-related class of some sort.

You need to either create the AlertDialog in your activity, or you need to pass your Activity to your ConnectDB class so the ConnectDB can use it for generating the dialog.

Comment: You've Cleared up my mind, I was thinking about this right now, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

To this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityClassName.this).create();
```

Make sure you are providing your **Activity's context** here (NOT application context i.e. `getApplicationContext()`). Don't get confused with *application context* and *activity context*, because they both are significant when it comes to initialize objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show an Alert Dialog from another class, you'll have to pass a instance of the activity to the other class and call the `runOnUiThread` method on it.

Here's how I do it (game being the activity):

```
game.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(game);
            builder.setTitle("Network Error");
            builder.setMessage("Please connect to the internet");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    game.finishGame();

                }
            });

            initialized = true;

            }

        });
```